# How to init config from memory on client go

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

```golang
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

The above code snippet demonstrates building the kubernetes config from input flags using `client-go`, but is there a way to construct the config from a kubeconfig in memory?

Comment: Why do you have to read the config from memory? Where does the config come from? Please show us your code.

Comment: @larsks I had a reason for this: my kubeconfig existed in a remote machine relative to the machine I was writing a program for. Also, the docs for RESTConfigFromKubeConfig mention that it should be used for 80% of programmatic access.

Answer (score 1):

Try [RESTConfigFromKubeConfig](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd#RESTConfigFromKubeConfig).

```golang
// RESTConfigFromKubeConfig is a convenience method to give back a restconfig from your kubeconfig bytes.
// For programmatic access, this is what you want 80% of the time
func RESTConfigFromKubeConfig(configBytes []byte) (*restclient.Config, error)
```

```golang
// Get the kubeconfig bytes from somewhere.
kubeConfigBytes := []byte("...")

config, err := clientcmd.RESTConfigFromKubeConfig(kubeConfigBytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}

// Do something with clientset.
fmt.Println(clientset)
```